# How to show Firebase images in SwiftUI using an ImageSlider or something similar

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, swiftui, carousel

I have been trying to do this for some time, but have not been able to achieve my goal. I would like to show images stored at Firebase in an Image Slider or carousel in SwiftUI. I am able to fetch and show a single image (that's a different thing). However, unable to load images from firebase to slider. The first part is to get url of images which I am not getting how to do it.

**Update**

This loads images but cant auto scroll or auto iterate, images load one after another than stops:

```
 func downImage(){
  
    let imageRef = Storage.storage()
    let loc = imageRef.reference().child("Images")
    loc.listAll{(result,error) in
        if error != nil{
            print("Ooops : ", error)
            return
        }
        
      
       for item in result!.items{
       let count = result?.items.count ?? 5 
       //provides actual count ie 3
       print("number of Images: ", self.count)
       print("images url : " , item)
            
            item.getData(maxSize: 15 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("\(error)")
                }
                guard let data = data else { return }
                
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  self.count = count
             //     self.actualImage.append(self.image)
                  self.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)!
                    
               }}}}}}
```

In Slider, images are shown but stops after loading third image:

```
struct ImageSlider: View {

@StateObject var imageList = FireImageModel()
 
 /* private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 3, on: .main, in: .common) 
       .autoconnect() */


var body: some View {
   

    TabView(){

     /*   ForEach(imageList.actualImage, id: \.self) { item in
      if foreach loop is used with actualImage appending Images no 
      image is shown or Index out of range error */

                Image(uiImage: imageList.image)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 3))
        .onAppear(){
            imageList.downImage()
        }
    }
```

If I apply the timer (commented out) with other settings it keeps updating selected image 0, selected image 1 but image never changes. Need images to auto scroll in this slider.

Comment: Do you really need to download them? Maybe it would be simpler to use AsyncImage with original URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your code, you are downloading the string url from Firebase into
`@Published var imageURL: [String] = []`. This does not download the `image` data, just the url string.

In your `loadImageURL`, try this, to store all the url strings into your `imageURL` array:

```
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let linq = link {
                    self.imageURL.append(linq)
                    print("url link : ", self.imageURL)
                }
```

In your `ImageSlider`, use something like this, instead of your `Image(item)`:

```
  AsyncImage(url: URL(string: item))
```

also,  change `@ObservedObject var imageList = FireImageModel()` to `@StateObject var imageList = FireImageModel()`

and, do not use `!`, anywhere in your code, it is a recipe for disaster.

EDIT-1:

Given your new code, try this simple example code, to try to find where your problem is:

```
struct ImageSlider: View {
    @StateObject var imageList = FireImageModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(imageList.actualImage, id: \.self) { item in
                Image(uiImage: item)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 222, height: 222)
            }
            .onAppear {
                imageList.downImage()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, do not use `!` anywhere in your code.

If that works, try this:

```
struct ImageSlider: View {
    @StateObject var imageList = FireImageModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if imageList.actualImage.count > 0 {
                TabView {
                    ForEach(imageList.actualImage, id: \.self) { item in
                        Image(uiImage: item)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                    }
                }
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            } else {
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            imageList.downImage()
        }
    }
}
```

You may also want to clean your `FireImageModel`, such as:

```
class FireImageModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var actualImage: [UIImage] = []

    func downImage() {
        let imageRef = Storage.storage()
        let loc = imageRef.reference().child("Images")
        loc.listAll{(result,error) in
            if error != nil{
                print("Ooops : ", error)
                return
            }
            if let images = result {
                print("number of Images: ", images.items.count)
                for item in images.items {
                    print("images url : " , item)
                    item.getData(maxSize: 15 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("\(error)")
                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if let theData = data, let image = UIImage(data: theData) {
                                self.actualImage.append(image)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: changed the method now directly downloading images used append also with image data but no image is shown in slider

Comment: updated my example code to try to find your issue.

Comment: How to Show Url Image and set  to auto Slider the Images data is coming  from API ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to display images in slider final prob was auto iteration. ForEach was throwing index out of range error(known prob) when directly using an array having image data so ans by @workingdogUkraine helped to resolve the error by putting check before entering the foreach. Auto iteration is done. Look into updated clean FireImageModel model by WorkingDog, below is the slider struct:

```
 struct ImageSlider: View {

@StateObject var imageList = FireImageModel()
@State private var currentIndex = 0
@State var zoomed = false


private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 3, on: .main, in: .common) 
       .autoconnect()

var body: some View {
    // 2
    
    VStack {
    
              if imageList.actualImage.count > 0 {
                  GeometryReader{ proxy in
                      TabView(selection: $currentIndex){
                          ForEach(imageList.actualImage.indices, id: \.self) { 
                              item in
                              let sot = imageList.actualImage[item]
                              Image(uiImage: sot)
                              .resizable()
                              .scaledToFill()
                              .onTapGesture {
                                  self.zoomed.toggle()
                              }
                              .scaleEffect(self.zoomed ? 1.73 : 1)
                          }
                          .onReceive(timer, perform: {_ in
                              withAnimation(.spring(response: 1, 
                              dampingFraction: 1, blendDuration: 1)){
                            
                              currentIndex = currentIndex < 
                           imageList.actualImage.count ? currentIndex + 1 : 0
                          }
                        })
                  }
                  .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
                  .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height/3)
                  
                 }
                  
                  
              }else {
                  ProgressView()
              }
    }.background(.ultraThinMaterial)
          .onAppear {
              imageList.downImage()
          }
         
      }}
```

Images appear with non noticeable animation :), will like to add some cool animation, after every 3 seconds image changes

Comment: it looks better wo animation no sliding just image changes